# Dynamic procedure execution with 'table of varchar and sys_refcursor as an argument

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Trying to execute a procedure dynamically with DBMS_SQL that takes 'table of varchar' and sys_refcursor as an argument using the code below:

```
   DECLARE
   TYPE CriteriaMap IS TABLE OF VARCHAR (100)
                          INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (100);

   o_cursor             SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_cid                INTEGER;
   v_dummy              INTEGER;
   v_date_to_run        DATE := SYSDATE;
   v_sql_execute_proc   VARCHAR2 (1024);
   v_filter_criteria    CriteriaMap;
BEGIN
   v_sql_execute_proc :=
      'begin MY_PROCEDURE(:v_date_to_run, :filter_criteria, :o_cursor); end;';
   v_cid := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
   DBMS_SQL.parse (v_cid, v_sql_execute_proc, DBMS_SQL.native);
   DBMS_SQL.bind_variable (v_cid, 'v_date_to_run', v_date_to_run);
   DBMS_SQL.bind_variable (v_cid, 'filter_criteria', v_filter_criteria);
   DBMS_SQL.bind_variable (v_cid, 'o_cursor', o_cursor);
   v_dummy := DBMS_SQL.execute (v_cid);
   DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (v_cid);
END;
```

as the result the following error is thrown

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 14, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BIND_VARIABLE'
```

Documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm says that BIND_VARIABLE takes only a limited number of data types and 'table of varchar' and sys_refcursor are not in the list.

Is there any workaround to pass arguments to a dynamic function which data types are not in the list?

Comment: are you on 10g then? as the tag you've assigned is oracle11g. especially important considering the major dbms sql API additions that were added in 11g .

Comment: DazzaL, database is 11g(11.2.0.2.0). Havn't noticed any significant changes in DBMS_SQL API.

Answer (score 0):

table of varchar is suppoorted through bind_array (though it has to be as per the spec in dbms_sql which is indexed by integer and not varchar2).

can you explain more on why you're using dynamic SQL in this case? as your example does not warrant dynamic SQL as the structure of the call is fixed here.

Comment: DazzaL thank you for your help.

Indeed DBMS_SQL has a varchar2 type:
`TYPE varchar2_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;`

Dynamic SQL is used to execute SQL queries in the procedures, retrieve parameters from `v_filter_criteria` variable and store result in sys_refcursor as an output variable.

Intention is to use dynamic procedures to avoid multiple 'when' conditions, such as:
`
  ..
  when v_sql_name = 'MY_PROCEDURE' then MY_PROCEDURE(o_cursor, date_to_run, filter_criteria);
  ..
`

Comment: Example procedure `CREATE OR REPLACE procedure MY_PROCEDURE(o_cursor out sys_refcursor, date_to_run in date, filter_criteria in reportcriteriamap)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN o_cursor FOR
SELECT * from dual
            WHERE param = filter_criteria('PARAM_A')
            ;
END MY_PROCEDURE;
/`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old... but if anyone encounters this - it is possible (in 11g, not sure about earlier) to convert the sys ref cursor to a cursor number, bind it, and then transform it to a refcursor after the execute - something like:

```
declare
   vSQL varchar2(1000) := 'declare 
                              v_rc sys_refcursor;
                           begin 
                              open v_rc for select ''this is a test'' from dual;
                              :v_cursor_number := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(v_rc);
                           end;';
   v_rc sys_refcursor;
   v_cursor_number   NUMBER;
   v_cur number;
   v_result number;

   vFetchValue varchar2(20);
begin
   --open the cursor
   v_cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   --parse
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(v_cur, vSQL, dbms_sql.native);
   --bind the cursor number
   DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(v_cur, 'v_cursor_number', v_cursor_number);
   --execute
   v_result := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(v_cur);
   -- get back the value of the bind cursor number
   DBMS_SQL.VARIABLE_VALUE(v_cur,'v_cursor_number', v_cursor_number);
   --transform it to a standard sys_refcursor
   v_rc := DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR (v_cursor_number);
   --close the cursor
   DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_cur);

   fetch v_rc into vFetchValue;
   close v_rc;
   dbms_output.put_line(vFetchValue);

end;
/
```